# How to correctly configure a static resource handler into a Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, resources

I am pretty new in Spring and I have the following problem.

In a tutorial I found this configuration class example:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.mycompany.myproject.web.controller" })
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
.................
..............

}
```

How exactly works the **addResourceHandlers()** method in the previous code snippet? Looking on the official documentation it seems to understand that it **add handlers to serve static resources such as images, js, and, css files from specific locations under web application root, the classpath, and others.**

In the previous case it is used to add static resources related to Twitter BootStrap framework (something like CSS files and JavaScript files).

The problem is that the project on which I am working don't use Java configuration but use **XML configuration** and I have some problem to understand how can I do the same thing of the previous code snippet into my XML configuration.

In particular I have a **servlet-context.xml** file that contains the MVC configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="it.hp.miur" />

</beans:beans>
```

I think that I have to put this configuration into this file but I don't know how do it. Can you help me?

Tnx